# How to plot 2 functions with Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I am struggling to plot evaluated function and Cbebyshev approximation.
I am using Julia 1.2.0.

EDIT: Sorry, added completed code.

```
using Plots
pyplot()
mutable struct Cheb_struct
    c::Vector{Float64}
    min::Float64
    max::Float64
end

function cheb_coeff(min::Float64, max::Float64, n::Int, fn::Function)::Cheb_struct
    struc = Cheb_struct(Vector{Float64}(undef,n), min, max)
    f = Vector{Float64}(undef,n)
    p = Vector{Float64}(undef,n)
    max_plus_min = (max + min) / 2
    max_minus_min = (max - min) / 2
    for k in 0:n-1
        p[k+1] = pi * ((k+1) - 0.5) / n
        f[k+1] = fn(max_plus_min + cos(p[k+1])*max_minus_min)
    end
    n2 = 2 / n
    for j in 0:n-1
        s = 0
        for i in 0:n-1
            s += f[i+1]*cos(j*p[i+1])
        struc.c[j+1] = s * n2
    end
end
    return struc
end

function approximate(struc::Cheb_struct, x::Float64)::Float64
    x1 = (2*x - struc.max - struc.min) / (struc.max - struc.min)
    x2 = 2*x1
    t = s = 0
    for j in length(struc.c):-1:2
        pom = s
        s = x2 * s - t + struc.c[j]
        t = pom
    end
    return (x1 * s - t + struc.c[1] / 2)
end

fn = sin
struc  = cheb_coeff(0.0, 1.0, 10, fn)
println("coeff:")

for x in struc.c
    @printf("% .15f\n", x)
end

println("\n     x         eval          approx      eval-approx")
for x in struc.min:0.1:struc.max
    eval = fn(x)
    approx   = approximate(struc, x)
    @printf("%11.8f %12.8f  %12.8f   % .3e\n", x,eval, approx, eval - approx)
    display(plot(x=eval,y=approx))
end
```

I am getting empty plot window.

I would be very grateful if someone coould how to plot these two functions.

Comment: Please include working code that other people can try to run. You have not defined `struc` and `approximate`, so we cannot run this code. Also, you appear to plot just one point at a time, presumably, you should try to plot a whole line in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a working code as an example.

However the code below can show you how to plot:

```
using Plots
pyplot()
fn = sin
approxf(x) = sin(x)+rand()/10
x = 0:0.1:1
evalv = fn.(x)
approxv   = approxf.(x)
p = plot(evalv,approxv)
using PyPlot
PyPlot.display_figs() #needed when running in IDE such as Atom
```